# Post office at Heathrow open?

Tags: lhr, mail

Does anyone know the current status of post at Heathrow?  I am arriving at Heathrow on Dec Saturday 18th 2021. I would like to mail a package out by next day mail. I am finding conflicting information about if the Post Office in Terminal 3 is currently open, and if there is a post office in Terminal 5. I can't find a phone no. for the terminal 5 post office and no one answers the number I have for the terminal 3 post office.

Comment: Have you checked [postoffice.co.uk](https://www.postoffice.co.uk/branch-finder/0770256/heathrow-airport-terminal-three), who should know? They say T3 is closed, probably why they don't answer the phone, but [T5 is open](https://www.postoffice.co.uk/branch-finder/0210250/heathrow-airport-terminal-5) except Christmas day.

Comment: @ChrisH-UK Strangely enough, the heathrow.com website only refers to a post office in Terminal 3, and the shop list does not show any post office (and the category filter exists but is disabled). It would probably be worth it contacting Heathrow (by phone or via Twitter) to have a more accurate answer.

Comment: The Terminal 5 map does not show any post office either, only postboxes.

Comment: @jcaron it's also missing from Openstreetmap.org,